# angular scrollbar container shrinks itself when grouping

Tags: html, angular, layout, scroll

I'm trying to implement Perfect Scrollbar in my angular project but some reason when I added a text right above it, it shrinks itself. If I get rid of the text above, it become a normal side (applied my width & height).

I'm place those two inside mat-grid-tile. any suggestion on what is happening? I tried to change the the height of the scroll bar but it changing nothing.

```
    <mat-grid-tile [rowspan]="5" [colspan]="7">
      <div>
        <div>
          <p style="margin-bottom: 240px; margin-right: 250px; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px; ">Workspaces</p>
        </div>
        <perfect-scrollbar style="background-color: white; border-radius: 5px; font-size: 5px;">
          <div>
            <button mat-stroked-button style="width: 135px; height: 25px; margin: 20px; font-size: 8px; margin-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 30px;">Filter by super Tags</button>
          </div>
        </perfect-scrollbar>
      </div>
```

[This is what it look like right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ambY.png)

Comment: Can you provide a repro of your problem on stackblitz please ?

Comment: oh hey Quentin, I tried to uploaded the code on Stackblitz but I got an error on scrollbar since I installed the package and also on MatGridListModule so I'm not sure if I can make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [repro on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qx6cke?file=src/app/grid-list-overview-example.html)

And here is the code in case stackblitz does not works :

```
<mat-grid-list cols="7" rowHeight="1:1">
  <mat-grid-tile [rowspan]="5" [colspan]="7">
      <div>
        <div>
          <!-- removed : margin-bottom: 240px; margin-right: 250px; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px; -->
          <p style="">Workspaces</p>
        </div>
         <!-- Added: height: 200px, it's required -->
        <perfect-scrollbar style="background-color: white; border-radius: 5px; height: 200px;">
          <div>
            <div>coucou</div><br>
            <div>coucou</div><br>
            <div>coucou</div><br>
            <div>coucou</div><br>
            <div>coucou</div><br>
            <div>coucou</div><br>
            <div>coucou</div><br>
            <div>coucou</div><br>
            <div>coucou</div><br>
            <div>coucou</div><br>
            <button mat-stroked-button style="width: 135px; height: 25px; margin: 20px; font-size: 8px; margin-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 30px;">Filter by super Tags</button>
          </div>
        </perfect-scrollbar>
      </div>
  </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

Is it what you wanted to do ?

Also you should externalize your styling in a css file, it will be much easier to read.

Comment: wow that you so much.. I thought I added the height but I guess I forgot. he he thanks